# autoload vs include or require in php

Tags: php, open-source, autoload

I am currently going through autoloading and l realize that autoloading may just be the same with require or include and I have come to the conclusion that perhaps there could be an advantage for using autoloading instead of require or include.
What is the advantage of using autoload instead of require or include to use a class in a php file?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? No need to write the require/include lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are working in a file, you might have to require in other files at the top in order to use their functionalities.

Depending on the requirement, that list can get very long. And doing this in every file is tedious,unclean and can be avoided.

Hence, autoload your files.

For example, you can keep all your classes under one folder named classes. Then make a bootstrap file where you can write the autoloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

To make this work, all you have to do is keep the file name and class name the same.

Henceforth you need to require only this bootstrap file and all your classes will be autoloaded.

Comment: I can also add all classes in an array an autoload all classes without including many files, am l right?

Comment: How can you do that?You can require/include files, not arrays. You might have other folders like controllers,system where there are classes. In that case you can make an array of the folder names and while looping through them, you require in the class.And you do this inside the spl_autoload_register function.

Comment: Its exactly what l meant, l usually use controllers with frameworks, though, say you are not using a framework, does one really need a controller?

Comment: You can work in core php if you want to do without them. Controllers are a part of frameworks because they implement the MVC design pattern and using MVC is a standard practise in the industry as it separates out the view and the logic.

Comment: Thank you Budhaditya Biswas

Comment: Just for interest, I use to require my class files like so:

`foreach (glob(MY_DEFINED_INCLUDE_PATH.'/classes/class.*.php') as $filename){
    require_once $filename;
}`

Is there any disadvantage in doing it this old fashion way? Sorry, I am still a PHP beginner ..