# Should I prefer require instead of require_once inside spl_autoload_register() callback

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

In example at [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) loader uses `include` inside it:

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

But there are at least several ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571248/autoload-vs-include-or-require-in-php), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143413/how-does-phps-spl-autoload-register-resolve-circular-dependencies-with-require)) autoloading related SO questions where `require_once()` appears.
In fact, my own code already uses `require_once()` too.

So, my question is: **does it really matters how to `include`/`require` source files inside autoloader callback**?

I think I understand difference between `include` and `require`, question about `…_once` part :)

When `require_once()` is used in that callback, will PHP actually do additional checks against list of already required files?
Is there risk to double-require some file if we will use`require()`? Will `require()` be faster than `require_once()`?

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    require_once('classes/' . $class . '.class.php');
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

VS

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    require('classes/' . $class . '.class.php');
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

Comment: `require` will be fine so long as your classes are one per file. The autoloader won't trigger if the class is already found (i.e. it already required it) so `require_once` is redundant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a  [primitive benchmark](https://gitlab.com/strm50/autoloader-test).

I wasn't be able to see significant difference betwen this two approaches (`require` vs `require_once`).  Maybe problem in "benchmark" itself, feel free to send PR to fix it :)

Most visible changes in execution time had took place when some other process has used disk while test running.

Both approaches had shown ~0.062 for 300 classes on 7200rpm HDD.

```
> php -v
PHP 7.2.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```